# Simulated write denied?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with the following structure:

```
- pets
   - $pet1
      - mod:
      - name:
      - dateCreated:
      - members:
```

I want to make sure when a new pet is being added under "pets" it has all the proper children (mod, name, dateCreated, and members). However, when implementing the following rule I'm getting a write denied error in the simulator:

```
"rules": {
  "pets": {
    "$pet": {
      ".write": "(data.val() == null && newData.hasChildren(['mod','members','dateCreated','name']))"
```

[image: simulatorPic]

Can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong please? Here's a picture of the actual simulator:

[image: otherPic]